# how to read response in python and calling def

Tags: python, json, request

I have a if statement which i am trying to replace a variable.
After replacing the variable how do i call def parse_again
Below are my code i am trying out my.

match4 is a string and rep1 too

rep1 variable is a global variable

```
if results == "":

    url = 'myapiIP'
            postdata = {regex:match4}
            req = urllib2.Request(url)
            req.add_header('Content-Type','application/json')
            data = json.dumps(postdata)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req,data)
    rep1 = response.content <<<trying out (read the response not working)
    parse_again() <<<<trying out (trying to call my def parse )
```

my def parse:

```
  def parse_again(self, response):
    .........
```

Assuming that the api gives a right response how do i read it and replace variable rep1 with it and how do i re run the def parse to run through the parse_again ( my def parse works fine )

Please tell me which part u do not understand as i am bad at phrasing question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working inside a class, so your eventual call to parse_again should be

```
self.parse_again(response)
```